# Is there any way to get a portion version of jQuery UI with my desired features?

Tags: jquery-ui

I would like to use only `easing.easeOutQuint` and `animate` feature of jQuery UI. How can I get a smaller piece of code rather than the `jquery-ui.js`? I want to just put the code directly in my page.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/download/ lets you pick and choose.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know which ones to choose so that I can only use `.animate({})`.

Comment: `.animate()` is part of jQuery, not jQuery UI. http://api.jquery.com/animate/